# Detecting Success or Failure of AJAX Post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an `<a>` tag and I want to use a jQuery handler to perform an Ajax post before the browser transfers to the target link. In addition, if my Ajax post fails, I want to cancel the transfer.

This seemed like a simple task. If the post succeeds, I return true from my handler. Otherwise, I return false.

The problem is that `$.post()` doesn't return a value. Rather, I need to provide a callback function, which is called after the post completes and receives the results of the post. However, by this time it's too late to know what value my original handler should return.

```
$('#navagateAway').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $('#event-id').val();
    $.post('@Url.Action("UpdateBeforeNavagating")', { id: myId }, afterUpdate);
}
```

How can my handler determine if it should return true or false when the results won't be known until my callback is called?

Comment: A full [jquery.ajax() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) would help you a lot

Comment: @ARMBouhali: I have access to the reference like anyone else. If you really find something there that would address my specific question, I'm sure you'll let us know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best you can do prevent the default action then emulate it when the ajax succeeds

```
$('#navagateAway').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $('#event-id').val();
    var href = this.href;
    $.post('@Url.Action("UpdateBeforeNavagating")', { id: myId }, function(){window.location = href});
}
```

Comment: This seems right. I had hoped I could do this without duplicating the built-in functionality (my actual program is more complex).

Comment: Because the event handler is going to finish after it triggers the ajax call (not waiting for the response), this really is the only way to do it that I know of.

Answer (score 2):

From the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

```
jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ] [, dataType ] )
```

> is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

so move your code to using [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '@Url.Action("UpdateBeforeNavagating")',
  data: { id: myId },
  success: afterUpdate,
  error: function_on_fail // your fn
});
```

Comment: But how does this allow me to control the return value from my original handler? I want to cancel the click on the link if it fails. I don't get how to do that from your code.

Comment: BTW, the shorthand `$.post()` also supports success and fail callbacks. So I don't really see what this adds.

Comment: I don't understand, you want the `$.post` to be blocking instead of asynchronous? Then set `async: false`

Comment: The page you use specifies the return message. It may be text 'OK' or a page containing specific elements.

Just as if you access it via the browser

Answer (score 1):

Use `.fail()` and `.done()` like this:

```
$('#navagateAway').on('click', function (e) {
    var id = $('#event-id').val();

    $.post('@Url.Action("UpdateBeforeNavagating")', { id: myId }, afterUpdate)
    .done(function(){
        alert('Success');
    })
    .fail(function(){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't address the question. My handler needs to be able to allow or cancel the original click.

Comment: i have updated my answer, place the `e.preventDefault()` on `fail` function to cancel the click.

Comment: I don't believe that would work as the event handler will continue to the end of the code block before the .fail callback is triggered. By then, there won't be an original event to prevent.

Answer (score 0):

`@Url.Action("UpdateBeforeNavagating")` is the submit url of your page. I guess it's in your site so it's doing particular processing at form reception.

The return value of the requested page (printed data) can be manipulated in `$.ajax()` with success : function

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '@Url.Action("UpdateBeforeNavagating")',
  data: { id: myId },
  success: function(msg){ if (msg == 'somevalue') /* do somthing */ else /*do something else */}
});
```

'failure' field means that the page returned an error, anything other than HTTP 
200 code

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I don't think you understood the question. Musa's answer seemed most relevant.